# Usage of HTML private input type

Tags: html

A site I came across uses input type="private" for its password Form field. However, I searched online and it seems that "private" is not one of the defined types (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)? What does it do and where can I search for more details on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type=private` simply isn't one of the default values that the browser would recognize.

However, you're free to give it any type you want, you could give it a `type="peanutbutter"`.

Doesn't matter, cause what matters is: now you can call that input type with jquery or something by doing `input[type=peanutbutter]` to select all inputfields with that specific type using javascript, jquery or css.

My guess is that `type=private` doesn't exist, but it's simply something used by that company to manipulate the inputfields.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `private` is not one of the HTML input types. [(MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Even semantically, the input type 'private' does not make any sense. Input element with unknow type is rendered as `text` type by default. So here `private` is just some gibberish for the render.

I guess the site you came across might be doing for any specific use-case - CSS selector like `input[type="private"]` or with JavaScript - which is not the way to do. As this not standard, it should not be used.